# Check if checkbox is not checked with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox, jquery-validate

How can I check if checkbox is not checked with jQuery? Is there something that is negative of `.click(....)`?

Here is my code:

```
$().ready(function () {
        // validate UserSettings form on keyup and submit
        $('#CheckBox').click(function () {
            $("#TextBox").validate({
                rules: {
                    NextLocation: {
                        required: true
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This code works in reverse than what I want (if sets true when checkbox is checked).
I want required to not be set to true if checkbox is checked

Comment: Did you try just typing false instead of true ?

Comment: It would be best to also show your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!` to make sure that this gets executed when the current condition is `false`. So, when you write a situtaion where the code get executed when the checkbox is checked, just add `!` in the start of the code as I did. And you'll get the code working. Other functions will be just the way they are `.click()` and so on.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () { // use #CheckBox if you want to
   if(!$(this).prop('checked')) { // if NO checkbox checked
     $('div').html("checked");
   }
})
```

This will look if the checkbox isn't checked!

Answer (score 1):

Your code...

```
$().ready(function () {
    // validate UserSettings form on keyup and submit
    $('#CheckBox').click(function () {
        $("#TextBox").validate({
            rules: {
                NextLocation: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

... has the following issues...

1)  `$().ready()` is not recommended [as per jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  Use `$(document).ready()` instead.

2)  You cannot attach `.validate()` to an input element.  It only gets attached to the `<form>` element.

3)  The `.validate()` method is only used for *initializing* the plugin, not for *testing* anything.  Therefore, it typically does not belong inside of a `click` handler.  You would fire `.validate()` *only once* as soon as the form is constructed, typically within the DOM ready handler.

4)  If you want to make something `required` depending on the state of something else, you would use the `depends` method within the `required` rule.

My working demo below shows that the text field named `NextLocation` is only `required` when the checkbox named `check` is not checked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  // DOM ready handler

    $('#myform').validate({  // attach to form to initialize plugin with options
        rules: {
            NextLocation: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        return !$('input[name="check"]').is(':checked');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="check" />
    NextLocation: <input type="text" name="NextLocation" />
</form>
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/dymmw/**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($("#CheckBox").prop('checked')){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your if statement

```
 $('#checkbox').is('checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches:

A - You can change it using the **click** function an checking there:

```
...
('#CheckBox').click(function () {
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
       ...
   }
});
...
```

B - Use the **change** function, which I'd prefer

```
$("#CheckBox").change(function(){
   if($(this).checked){
      ...
   }

});
```